# How can I export mudbox joints to .fbx?

Tags: unity, rigging, fbx

When I export my Mudbox mesh (level 1), with its skeleton selected, to a .fbx and import it into unity, I don't get the bones/joints/skeleton/whatever under my mesh in the hierarchy.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry the bones joint things in Mudbox are not exportable, they aren't real bones like the bones are in Max or Maya, mudbox joints are more like the deformer modifier in 3ds Max. Sorry its not that u are missing anything its just how Mudbox works sorry, I also tryed a similar thing but it didn't work for me either. So don't worry.